# Can I install java 8 on Travis CI for a python project?

Tags: java, python

I have a python project that also requires Java 8 to run the tests and thus fails because Travis CI uses Java 7 by default. I know this can be updated if the project is a Java project but mine is python. I have a travis.yml file like below:

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
...
```

I have tried installing Java 8 using the following methods

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
...
```

and

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
script:
- jdk_switcher use oraclejdk8
...
```

Any idea if this is possible? I'm thinking it might not be.

Comment: From https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Installing-a-Second-Programming-language

        before_install:
           - java install oraclejdk8

Answer (score 5):

In the [container-based infrastructure](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/) the following should do it:

```
language: python
 python:
   - "2.7"
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java8-installer
...
```

Comment: This syntax `oracle-java8-installer` has changed!  As per the other answer, it should be `oracle-java8-set-default`

Answer (score 5):

As of 14 November 2016, with [this commit](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/commit/3d65009c2), the following installs and activates Java 8:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java8-set-default
```